# How to read & display time in Navbar of Shiny R Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I want to display Last Updated time in the navbar of shiny R. For that I'm storing the last updated time in csv file which I will be using to read in the server.R but I'm unable to figure out how to display that time on the rightmost side of the navbar. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You

```
    shinyUI(
       navbarPage(
              title = 'Welcome',
               tabPanel('Overview',
           tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel('Forward',
                    fluidRow(
                      DT::dataTableOutput("view_fwd"),width = 6
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel('Reverse',
                    fluidRow(
                      DT::dataTableOutput("view_rvo"),width = 6
                    ))

           ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage(
    title = 'Welcome',
    tabPanel('Overview',
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel('Forward',
                        fluidRow(
                          DT::dataTableOutput("view_fwd"),width = 6
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel('Reverse',
                        fluidRow(
                          DT::dataTableOutput("view_rvo"),width = 6
                        ))

             )),
              tabPanel(tags$ul(class='nav navbar-nav', 
                               style = "padding-left: 550px;", htmlOutput("time"))) # here you output time, need to positions on the left side by 550px
    )

)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$time <- renderUI({

    as.character(strptime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "EET"))


  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: No prob. If the answer was useful, you can upvote it.

Comment: I did But It's giving a msg like "people with less than 15 Reputation's vote are recorded but do not change the public display post score". But i will come back and do give it a upvote. Also is there a way to make it unclickable like when i point my mouse on it and tap, it open's up a new page of its own like the Overview page. Any way to make that not happen ?

Comment: I think it better to use a custom navbar, not the default navbarPage as all objects in navbarPage  is clickable links. Probably, you should create a new ticket for this.

Answer (score 1):

With some css and Javascript you can let the time float to the right and disable click events on that tab. You would need the package `shinyjs` for it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- '
shinyjs.init = function() {
$(".nav").on("click", ".disabled", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
}
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
}
.navbar ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}
.navbar ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  color: black !important;
}
                       "))),
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = "init"),
  navbarPage(
    title = 'Welcome',

    tabPanel('Overview',
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel('Forward',
                        fluidRow(
                          DT::dataTableOutput("view_fwd"),width = 6
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel('Reverse',
                        fluidRow(
                          DT::dataTableOutput("view_rvo"),width = 6
                        ))

             )),
    tabPanel(tags$ul(class='nav navbar-nav', 
                     style = "padding-left: 5px; float: right;", htmlOutput("time")))
  )

)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    toggleClass(condition = input$foo,
                class = "disabled",
                selector = ".navbar ul > li:nth-child(2)")
  })

  output$time <- renderUI({
    as.character(strptime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "EET"))
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, This one really helped me.

Comment: Hi, I tried up voting the answer but a message is being displayed to me saying "people with less than 15 Reputation's vote are recorded but do not change the public display post score". Your answer did help me a lot and I will come back to upload it when I have more than 15 REP.